# Saved search report in Netsuite

Tags: web-services, report, netsuite

I want to create a report in Netsuite ERP that shows me the information about Departments Sales and Budget by Month. I think I can achieve this by creating a saved search that chooses this items, however I don't understand under which category I can find this fields. A saved search would be ideal as I am trying to authomatize the reports in a java application, and I discovered that I can call the savedSearch results.

I found the Department under the standard Criteria in the subcategory "Owner..." and I added a Date standard criteria with the values "within this month", however I have not found the group that contains all the Sales/Income/Margin or the budget (though, I found an aggregation sum function that may be used along with a field). I will appreciate any help. Also, will the addition of this fileds be enough to get the Sales X Department X Date information or do I have to use a different join method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to combine two saved searches to achieve this.One on budgets for the period you need. The department column is available on the budgets saved search. 
The other would be transactions for the period. Generally budgets are against posting transactions so Invoices, Cash Sales, Credit Memos and Cash Refunds would be in your other search. If you group those by Department you could then combine the two searches in code to create your own budget vs actuals report.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't noticed that I created my savedSearch as a Payment rather than a transaction. I was able to create it correctly through the Transaction Saved Search option. I would greatl appreciate if you have an answer to this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35218144/netsuite-get-transaction-saved-search-java